# installing EGit under Eclipse Luna (4.4.1)

Tags: eclipse, egit

Installing EGit under Eclipse seems to be a moving target. All instructions I saw differ in some way and at the moment I'm clueless as to how proceed in installing EGit.

Where do I start?

What are the required steps?

Comment: Many of the Eclipse downloads include eGit - see if you have a 'Team > Git' in the Preferences

Answer (score 5):

First, check whether your Eclipse distribution already contains EGit or not. If yes, you will have a *Team*/*Git* page in the preferences.

If not, you can do one of the following:

1. Install it from the Eclipse Marketplace: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egit-git-team-provider - simply drag-and-drop the install link to your eclipse instance.
2. Open the new software install dialog from the *Help*/*Install New Software*, look for the *Luna*  update site (the yearly release repository already added to the list of update sites) and search for the EGit features (available in the Collaboration category).
3. Follow the instructions from the EGit homepage: https://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/

Comment: Thanks. I finally managed the install to work with method 1. (drag and drop the installer package). Methods 2 and 3 did not work. It looked like the Egit download page did not exist, resp. the page existed but the download link did not work. It seemed to point to itself.