# How do you install JGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, jgit

I read about this nice [Eclipse plugin called JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/download/) which allows one to use Git without installing it on the machine and commit from within Eclipse.

However, on their page, there are no instructions on how to install it. I've also tried "Install New Software" in Eclipse, but it was unable to find JGit.

How do you install it?

Comment: I think Eclipse has git by default, u don't need to install one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is mentioned on [this page](https://eclipse.org/jgit/download/). Quoting:

> JGit can be installed from the EGit repository:
>
> - Main Site: http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates (Recommended)
> - Mars Site (Mars.1 currently has JGit 4.0.3): http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars

When you select "Install New Software..." in Eclipse, you should enter the URL: `http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at EGit instead. JGit is the base API, while EGit is the Eclipse integration.

Take a look at this response too: [installing EGit under Eclipse Luna (4.4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801721/installing-egit-under-eclipse-luna-4-4-1)

Answer (score 0):

[JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/download/) is a library implementing git in Java, it also provides a command line tool, if you want integration into Eclipse you should install [EGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/) which uses JGit to provide git integration in Eclipse